# Looking for a starting point to solve a PDE with vector-coefficients

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, vector

I am looking for a good source for Mathematica in order to solve a PDE with vector coefficients.

I have found this:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html

and in this text it shows an example of the equation I am looking to solve,

Quote:

"
What types of equations can be solved with the finite element method as implemented in NDSolve? Consider a single partial differential equation in :

[image: PDE]

The PDE is defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here is the dependent variable for which a solution is sought. The coefficients m,d ,a and are scalars; $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$  are vectors; and c is an × matrix.

"end quote

My case is simpler, but is defined in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and the vectors are $u$, and $v$, while $\delta$, $\alpha$ and $\tau$ are vector products, so scalars.

[image: my__pde]

The problem is that this source at Wolfram gives no example on how to solve the first equation, so I have no starting point on how to formulate the code.

I started preparing the first code without coefficients and vectors:

```
pde = D[psi[x, y,z,t],x] - D[psi[x, y,z,t],y]+D[psi[x, y,z,t],z]- D[psi[x, y,z,t],z]+D[psi[x, y,z,t],y] == 0

soln = DSolve[pde, psi[x,y,z,t], {x,y,z,t}]
```

Then I make a version with some dummy vectors:

```
pde ={1,2,3,5}⋅  D[psi[x, y,z,t],x] -{1,2,3,4}⋅ D[psi[x, y,z,t],y]+{1,2,2,4}⋅ D[psi[x, y,z,t],z]-{1,3,3,4}⋅  D[psi[x, y,z,t],z]+D[psi[x, y,z,t],y] == 0
soln = DSolve[pde, psi[x,y,z,t], {x,y,z,t}]
```

But then I get the error "List encountered within"...

What is the best way to set this up properly?

Thank you

Comment: Define: `psi[x_, y_, z_, t_] := {
  psiX[x, y, z, t],
  psiY[x, y, z, t],
  psiZ[x, y, z, t]
  , psiT[x, y, z, t]}` - then this works: `With[{p = psi[x, y, z, t]}, 
 pde = {1, 2, 3, 5} - D[p, x] - {1, 2, 3, 4} - 
    D[p, y] + {1, 2, 2, 4} - D[p, z] - {1, 3, 3, 4} - D[p, z] + 
    D[p, y] == {0, 0, 0, 0};
 soln = DSolve[pde, p, {x, y, z, t}]
 ]`

Comment: @flinty Thanks, but I get an error: "more input is needed"

Comment: I don't get that error - have you copied it correctly? I get a solution: `{{psiX[x, y, z, t] -> C[1][y, t][-2 x + z], 
  psiY[x, y, z, t] -> -x + C[2][y, t][-2 x + z], 
  psiZ[x, y, z, t] -> -x + C[3][y, t][-2 x + z], 
  psiT[x, y, z, t] -> x + C[4][y, t][-2 x + z]}}` - the C[...] are functions in this case, not constants.